# Getting text after URL in asp.net / URL Rewriting (sort of!)

Tags: c#, url, url-rewriting

My app is a very simple "one page" type app-
It has Default.aspx

I'm basically trying to get, for example:

> www.myappurl.com/this is my text

I want to get hold of `"this is my text"` from the above example.
This will be displayed on the page (for now)
I didn't really want to have to use any complext url rewriting things for this...
(My hosting provider uses IIS6)

I tried using a 404 handler, but this is a bit long winded, and i'm using shared hosting, that can't set the "execute url" on custom 404 pages.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a mapping for all requests with the * extension to the ASP.NET isapi dll (GET/POST) verbs. You will need to uncheck the "verify file is on disk" checkbox when mapping the extension in IIS. (In IIS7 integrated mode, you map the extension in the web.config as well). Note that this will caause everything to be served by asp.net, even images and script files, which can slow things down.

Then create a handler mapping in your web.config to a http handler you create. 
From there, in the ProcessRequest() method of the handler, you have access to the HttpContext that spawned the request and can manipulate the URL from there.

That is the easiest option, you could also create a HttpModule, or have the default page at root redirect to http://www.domain.com/default.aspx/this is my text, in the code-behind of default.aspx, you will be able to get the text following the page and slash.